# How to make TProgressColumn work when used with LiveBindings and datasets

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, livebindings, tgrid, delphi-xe7

My goal is to have a TGrid with several columns, connected to a TClientDataSet via LiveBindings. One of the columns is of type TProgressColumn.

The grid displays the data, but the progress bar column shows nothing (i.e. 0% progress).

The TProgressColumn is connected to a field of type ftInteger. The values in this field are between 0 and 100.

I've tried with ftSingle, but with no luck.
I set the type of the column to be TProgressColumn via ColumnStyle property, available under TLinkGridToDataSourceBindSourceDB/Columns.

The strange thing is that when I use TPrototypeBindSource to generate values - the TProgressColumn works, but only for ftUInteger values. It fails for ftInteger generators.

Here is a little demo (Delphi XE7):

[image: TProgressColumn issues]

When I put a breakpoint in TProgressCell.DrawCell() and step over the two conditions for Value.IsOrdinal and Value.IsType are skipped and ClampValue receives a value "Min" which is 0.
There seems to be something wrong with the value, passed to the function.

Is there something special when working with TProgressColumn? Do I need to use CustomFormat, CustomParse in TLinkGridToDataSourceColumn?

Is that a bug or I miss something?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to "nompa" the mystery was solved!

In fact "asInteger" is the well known property of the TField class i.e.:

```
someDataSet.fieldByName('myFieldName').asInteger
```

[image: TProgressColumn - SOLVED!]

In CustomFormat property you can get access to many things, including self.asInteger properties.
More information here:

1. [Using Custom Format and Parse Expressions in LiveBindings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Using_Custom_Format_and_Parse_Expressions_in_LiveBindings)
2. [Using binding expressions in the CustomFormat property of a TLinkPropertyToField component](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86PPmORQ7kY)
3. [Formatting your Fields](http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1226)
4. [How to treat an Integer field as a Boolean?](http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1490)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is string by default, not matter is a integer field. In property CustomFormat write AsInteger.
The value will be take as integer and the progress now is visible.